# How to handle expanding columns in Angular with data from an API?

Tags: javascript, html, angular, typescript

How to create dynamic column component in angular 15.

I have a problem understanding how to create a  column component , In problem i have a fixed div height 450px , when data come from api if data meet within  height data will show in 1st column but if its big data column can expand 2nd 3rd or 4th column .

my ts file

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { Subscription } from 'rxjs';
import { ApiServiceService } from 'src/app/shared/services/api-service/api-service.service';
@Component({
  selector: 'app-test',
  templateUrl: './test.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./test.component.scss']
})

export class TestComponent {

  order: any[] = []
  orderSubscription: Subscription;

  constructor(private apiService: ApiServiceService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.orderSubscription = this.apiService.getOrders().subscribe((res: any) => {
      this.order = res;
      console.log(this.order)
    })
  }

  ngAfterViewInit(): void {

    setTimeout(() => {
      let parentDiv: any = document.querySelector('.order-item');
      let childDiv: any = document.querySelector('.first-div');

      // Step 2: Define the desired height within the parent <div>
      let desiredHeight = childDiv.offsetHeight; // Change this value to your desired height

      // Step 3: Loop through child elements and collect elements from desired height
      let elementsFromHeight = [];
      let currentHeight = 0;

      for (let i = 0; i < childDiv.children.length; i++) {
        let child = childDiv.children[i];
        let offsetTop = child.offsetTop;

        currentHeight += child.offsetHeight;
        if (currentHeight >= desiredHeight) {
          let data = child.cloneNode(true);
          elementsFromHeight.push(data);
        }

      }

      // Step 4: Create a new div and append the collected elements

      if (currentHeight >= desiredHeight) {
        let myDiv = document.createElement("div");
        myDiv.classList.add("second-div");
        myDiv.style.backgroundColor = "#2c2626";
        myDiv.style.width = "340px";
        myDiv.style.marginRight = "20px";
        myDiv.style.borderLeft = "2px solid #eeeeee52";

        elementsFromHeight.forEach((element) => {
          myDiv.appendChild(element);
        });

        // Step 5: Add the new div inside the parent div
        parentDiv.appendChild(myDiv);
      }
    }, 60);

  }

  ngOnDestroy() {
    this.orderSubscription.unsubscribe();
  }

}
```

my html file

```
<div class="order-item" *ngFor="let item of order">
                <div class="first-div">
                    <ng-container *ngFor="let data of item.items">
                        <h3>{{data.itemNameoriginal}}</h3>
                        <ul *ngIf="data.subCartItemArrayList.length">
                            <li *ngFor="let subCartList of data.subCartItemArrayList">{{subCartList.itemNameoriginal}}
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </ng-container>
                </div>
            </div>
```

I cannot implement it. Can someone help me and explain it to me?

Answer (score 1):

What you need is a simple flex display with wrap mode like this:

```
.column {
  height: 200px;
  background-color: grey;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}
```

Here is a simple example: [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/jzgqoyhc/)

And don't manipulate the DOM in angular code. At least not this way.

Comment: Thank you for your response , in this case initially it will show a row and four columns when data come it will fit either one column or second or third column based on data can you assist me for this